# Workflow is not sending mails

Tags: workflow

below is my scenario:

Subsite 1- group 1 have no access on site, but given read/contribute access to a document library within. when users upload a document, a workflow is initiated and mails are sent

Subsite 2- group 1 have no access on site, but given read/contribute access to a list within.  a workflow is configured to send mails when a new item is added/existing item edited. No mails are sent when a user of group 1 make some changes. workflow is initiated, but the error show is "sharepoint workflow sending mail Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource". But when a user who has Full control on the list makes a change, mail is sent.

I tried some of the suggestions from other posts like activating "Workflows can use app permissions"  and in "Group settings  set Who can view the membership of the group to Everyone", but no luck.
Could someone please help?

Comment: What's your SharePoint Platform 2013 or 2010 ?

Comment: SharePoint online (Office 365)